# Windows phone proper way to display collection of items

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10

I have XML file with my items and I'm deserializing them into `ObservableCollection<UserControl>` and I want to put it to my `ItemsControl` with my own layout.

Now I've created my own UserControl to handle deserialized data to layout and ObservableCollection is binded to my ItemsControl but if I want to display more than 5-10 items my app if getting unresponsive for a while.

How can I avoid freezes? Should I use DataTemplate within ItemsControl or any other ideas? I'm wondering how its done in apps like twitter or reddit which have many entries and everything is working quite nice. Have already searched for reddit/twitter app source to look how they have implemented it, but without success.

**EDIT:**

xaml

```
  <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="items" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

c#

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        items.DataContext = _items;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<my_item> _items = new ObservableCollection<my_item>();
```

adding items

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
   {
       _items.Add(new my_item());
   }
```

`my_item` is my own UserControl with 2 small images, few buttons and a single `TextBlock`.

Comment: We need some code to identify the problem. Edit your question with some XAML and the creation of the items.

Comment: i've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ListView` which has a virtualizing panel for displaying items by default:

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding Items} >
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                   <!-- here goes your item layout -->
            </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Maybe one reason for your app "hanging" is if you are deserializing/parsing your XML file on the UI thread, especially if the XML file is large, so the solution to this problem is that you need to do the XML parsing on a background thread:

```
Task.Run(() => 
{
    var items = ParseXML();
});
```

**After edit:**

**1)**
Don't wrap an `ItemsControl` inside a `ScrollViewer`, because you will break the virtualization. The `ItemsControl` itself has its own `ScrollViewer` so there is no need of an additional one.

If you are on `Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime`, use `ItemsStackPanel` instead of `VirtualizingStackPanel`.

**2)**
It is recommended for lists with many items to use `DataTemplates` instead of filling it with UI elements. So rather create a data template from your user control:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <MyUserControl/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: i changed ItemsPanel of my ItemsControl to VirtualizingStackPanel so I think it is virtualizing like listView, or not? As I see u suggest to use DataTemplate instead of adding multiple UserControl? Im sure that is no caused by xml parser beacuse it freezes either with blank UserControl without filling data from xml and parsing xml.

Comment: How can I enable scrollviewer for my itemscontrol? do I need some tricky xaml or just there is an property to do so?

Comment: It should be enabled by itself. What is the parent element of your ItemsControl, when you remove the outer scroll viewer?

Comment: Grid, after small research I found that it will be better to use ListBox with blank Selection Template(to avoid selection behavior) what u think?

Comment: Ok, now I know you are on WP 8.0, use either LongListSelector or ListBox. It is recommended that you use LongListSelector to display flat lists instead of using a ListBox, as the performance of LongListSelector is better than that of a ListBox and it also supports full data and UI virtualization.

Comment: Nope, im on W10M theres not LongListSelector. So looks like I need to use ListBox.

Comment: No. If you are on Windows 10, which is Windows Runtime, then use `ListView`, and don't specify a custom `ItemsPanel`, as ListView uses a virtualized panel already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88317/discussion-between-argashan-and-kristian-vukusic).